# selecting remove duplicate entries using 2 fields from oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I am working with an Oracle Query where I'm returning a set of records.  My requirement is to eliminate duplicate records.  I have a table with a unique_customer_id, date, and a message_id.  I need to select only the most recent result for each customer and each message id.

In other words, I want potentially multiple unique_customer_id rows, but only one row for each message-id per customer

Edit for clarity:

In addition to this, I'd like to add additional data fields to the result set that can be non-unique such as customer_answer, channel...Thanks!

Ex.

```
    Joe    msg1    1/2/2013
    Joe    msg1    4/5/2013
    Joe    msg1    8/9/2013
    Joe    msg2    8/8/2013
    Joe    msg2    9/10/2013
    Jim    msg1    9/13/2013
```

should return

```
    Joe    msg1    8/9/2013
    Joe    msg2    9/10/2013
    Jim    msg1    9/13/2013
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unique_customer_id, message_id, MAX(date)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY unique_customer_id, message_id
```

Comment: This worked great for my original question. I've added more details above...I thought I'd figured out the rest of it already ;).  How can I add additional fields to this query without the distinct requirement?  I.E return the 3 above fields and three other non-unique fields...Thanks!

Comment: @flobbie1: Distinct only makes sure you don't get duplicate rows. It's fine to have 3 additional fields which are identical, as long as not every field is identical to another row. However, since it's a group by clause, you have to either add the rows to the group by, or have them in aggregate functions, like MAX() or SUM().